# Flutter app crashes on startup on local iOS device while works fine in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, crash, sms

I have a Flutter application working fine on the iOS simulator but when I run it on a [local iOS device](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-physical-ios-devices) it gets built correctly but crashes once I start it on the IPhone.

Checking the device logs I see something connected to the BackgroundSmsPlugin registerwithRegistrar which might be connected to the issue.

I used as dependency:

```
background_sms: ^0.0.4
```

But it appears it's for "Android only for now". But what in your opinion is the motivation behind the fact that on the iOS Simulator all works fine but when deployed on a local iOS device it does not even start?

Also I find it very hard to read logs when having the app on the local device; any recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [official package page](https://pub.dev/packages/background_sms), it is stated in the README that only Android is currently supported. That just by itself should stop you from trying to use it on any other platform without altering package code directly.

As for the inconsistency you describe, it is most likely due to the developer having defined IOS as supported in the `pubspec.yaml` file, probably for future proofing.

This makes it so the flutter engine does not immediately throw an [UnimplementedError](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/UnimplementedError-class.html) in development, allowing the package to run in an unsupported platform until an unimplemented method is called at run time in that specific platform, where an [UnsupportedError](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/UnsupportedError-class.html) will then be thrown.